# вывод json строки в php

Tags: php, json

у меня есть вопрос - у меня с бази-даных подгружаеться список , как мне переобразить его в json ?

```php
foreach ($data as $cat ) {
            $dates = ["time"=>$cat->time];
            $global = array_merge($global, $dates);
        }
        json_encode($global);

//в итоге я хотел бы получить что-то такого 
//{
// {12421123},
// {12421123},
// {12421123},
// {12421123}
//}

на даный момент вывод таков - Array ( [time] => 1661784991 )
только одна запись , хотя должно выводить все 
ставил вместо :
array_merge($global, $dates); => $global .= $dates;
и тогда выводил все записи но мне надо его включить как масив в масиве и после задекодить в JSON
```

Comment: [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) и должен возвращать JSON-представление данных.

Comment: Надо только `echo` добавить

Comment: не работает как надо

Comment: Тогда добавьте в описание вопроса, как на данный момент она работает и что выводит. Нажмите [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: изменил запись.

Comment: ```$dates = ["time"=>$cat->time];``` заменить на  ```$dates["time"][] = $cat->time;```

Comment: `$global[] = $cat->time` примерно такое.. array_merge сливает массивы.. а ключи time одинаковые) в итоге идет перезапись

Comment: – Jour а если у меня несколько параметров - например , $cat->time , $cat->name ?

Comment: @IgorBiyar `$global[] = [$cat->time, $cat->name]`

Comment: @IgorBiyar вообще, возможно, foreach лишний.. может быть проще $data сразу перегнать в JSON

Comment: согласен , так и сделаю